# Parsing a text file in Shell Script separated by comma and equalsTo sign

Tags: shell, parsing

I want to write a shell script that will parse each line of an input text file and give me output in format of key-value.

Sample Input line(s) ->

```
NAME=Bhavin,RollNo=123,Class=10,Rank=1 ( Line 1 )
EMPLOYEE=Prashant,EID=233,Role=Consultant ( Line 2 )
COMPANY=xyz,location=india ( Line 3 )
```

The expected Output is :

```
Name = Bhavin
RollNo = 123
Class = 10
Rank = 1
**********
EMPLOYEE=Prashant
EID=233
Role=Consultant
**********
COMPANY=xyz
location=india
**********
```

Thanks ,
Bhavin

Comment: This works for me to certain extent -

while IFS=, read -ra arr;
do
 echo ${arr[0]};
 echo ${arr[1]};
done

But , How do I know the number of key value pairs in each line ? It can vary

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using awk you can do:

```
awk -F '[ ,]+' '{for (i=1; i<=NF; i++) if (index($i, "=")) {
       split($i, a, "="); print a[1], "=", a[2]} print "**********"}' file
NAME = Bhavin
RollNo = 123
Class = 10
Rank = 1
**********
EMPLOYEE = Prashant
EID = 233
Role = Consultant
**********
COMPANY = xyz
location = india
**********
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a `sed` solution.  If the input file is called `input`, then run:

```
$ sed 's/=/ = /g; s/,/\n/g; s/$/\n**********/' input
NAME = Bhavin
RollNo = 123
Class = 10
Rank = 1
**********
EMPLOYEE = Prashant
EID = 233
Role = Consultant
**********
COMPANY = xyz
location = india
**********
```

#### How it works

`sed` is an editor.  The basic command used here is substitute which has the form `s/old/new/`.  We use three substitute commands:

- `s/=/ = /g`

  This puts spaces around all equal signs.  The `g` at the end of the command tells `sed` to perform this substitution on every equal sign on the line, not just the first.
- `s/,/\n/g`

  This replaces commas with newlines everywhere that a comma occurs.
- `s/$/\n**********/`

  After each line of input, this adds a line of stars.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the reply , this worked for me as well :-

```
HOME_DIR="/home/bhatiab/ashok/src/ExcessInterfaces";
MAINENTITY_FILENAME="MainEntities.log";

while read line
do
    ENTITY_NAME=`echo $line | cut -d "," -f1`
    echo "ENTITY_NAME = "$ENTITY_NAME""
    arr=$(echo $line | tr "," "\n")
    for x in $arr
    do
        echo "$x"
    done
    echo "********************";

done < ${HOME_DIR}/${MAINENTITY_FILENAME}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
awk 'gsub(/$/, "\n**********")' <INPUT | awk 'BEGIN { RS = "," } gsub(/=/, " = ")' | awk NF
```

Or use sed:

```
sed 's/$/\n**********/g; s/,/\n/g; s/=/ = /g' <INPUT
```

Answer (score 0):

`awk`-single-liner without loops or arrays :

```
{m,g}awk 'gsub(",","\n",$!(NF=NF))' OFS=' = ' ORS='\n**********\n' \
                                     FS==      RS='[(][^)]+[)][ \t]*\r?\n'
NAME = Bhavin
RollNo = 123
Class = 10
Rank = 1 
**********
EMPLOYEE = Prashant
EID = 233
Role = Consultant 
**********
COMPANY = xyz
location = india 
**********
```